# Is there a python function for assigning values to several elements in a list?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I used the code shown below to create a list of lists.
Code:

```
num = 782
sol=4
pop_size= [sol, num]
initial_population_1 = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.0, size=pop_size)
```

The list of lists is shown below:

```
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

How can I randomly assign five values that are greater than 0 but less than 10 to five elements in each list in the list?
Thank you very much!

Comment: do you want to assign 5 random numbers only to any 5 of the item in the genrated list and the rest to be zero?

Comment: Yes, it is what I am looking for.

Comment: i'll post the answer now and check if is that what you want..

Comment: @GhostOps It's three times thou ask the OP to check your answer, please be a little bit  patient.

Comment: @gboffi yeah, i will. thanks gboffi

Comment: That's a 2d numpy array, not a list of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have a list of lists, specifically a list of 4 lists, each of them containing 782 elements, all 0.0, and you want to set 5 elements at random to 1.0.

I'd like to mention that, as you are using Numpy, there is `np.zeros(shape)` that provides you with a zero-filled array, but whatever…

From your question it's not clear if you want to avoid to use twice the same location, but let's assume that you want to assign a random value to exactly 5 entries in each row

```
for row in initial_population_1:
    locations_used_in_this_row = 0
    while locations_used_in_this_row != 5:
        column = np.random.randint(num)
        if row[column] == 0.0:
            row[column] = np.random.rand()*10
            locations_used_in_this_row += 1
```

Comment: @Zzyy Look at the outer loop: instead of operating on all the rows, operate on the _remaining_ rows, like this `for row in initial_population_1[1:]:`